# Валидность группы инпутов

Tags: javascript, валидация, checkbox

Всем привет
Написал "слайдер" для  опросника. 
Есть проблема.
в 17 строке идет проверка на отмеченные чексбоксы и заполненные поля
возникает проблема в 4 слайде
там есть поля (обязательные для заполнения) и чекбокс (не обязателен)
вот тут он и не работает

если вместо && поставить || то будет игнорировать чексбоксы.
Прошу помощи у вас. Спасибо!

```
const _form = document.querySelector('.js-questionForm');
    const _control = document.querySelectorAll('.js-questionControl');
    const _number = document.querySelector('.js-questionNumber');


    Array.prototype.forEach.call(_control, el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', ev => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            const _target = ev.target || ev.currentTarget;
            const _parent = el.parentNode.parentNode;
            const _parentId = _parent.getAttribute('data-id');
            const _numberItem = _number.querySelector('span');
            const _numberValue = parseInt(_parentId);
            if (_target.classList.contains('js-questionNext')) {
                const _inputChecked = _parent.querySelector('input:checked');
                const _inputText = _parent.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
                if (_inputChecked || _inputText) {
                    if (_parentId !== '4') {
                        _number.classList.add('active');
                        _numberItem.innerHTML = `${1+_numberValue}`
                    } else {
                        _number.classList.remove('active');
                    }
                    if (_inputText) {
                        console.log(_inputText.vallue)
                        if (_inputText.vallue = '') {
                            const _error = _parent.querySelector('.error');
                            _error.classList.add('active');
                            setTimeout( () => {
                                _error.classList.remove('active')
                            }, 4000)
                        } else {
                            let _traX = _parentId;
                            _form.style.transform = `translateX( -${100*_traX}%)`;
                        }
                    }
                    let _traX = _parentId;
                    _form.style.transform = `translateX( -${100*_traX}%)`;
                } else {
                    const _error = _parent.querySelector('.error');
                    _error.classList.add('active');
                    setTimeout( () => {
                        _error.classList.remove('active')
                    }, 4000)
                }
            } else if (_target.classList.contains('js-questionPrev')) {
                if (_parentId !== '2') {
                    _numberItem.innerHTML = `${_numberValue-1}`
                } else {
                    _number.classList.remove('active');
                }
                let _traX = _parentId - 2;
                _form.style.transform = `translateX( -${100*_traX}%)`;
            }

        })
    });
```

Пример тут https://jsfiddle.net/DetyaJah/yr8kb7Lu/

Answer (score 0):

Я изменил выбор input для поиска значения в них. Так как код:

```
const _inputText = _parent.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
```

Найдет только первый input, а у вас их два.

У меня получилось это вот так, надеюсь это то что вам надо.
https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/gjNLEe?editors=1111